How to redirect to another website with tauri + vite + typescript?
I'm making an app with tauri + vite + typescript, but when I want to redirect to another page from my script, it doesn't allow me to redirect the webview to another html. How can I redirect the webview to a different web page?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
